# Ruby: How do I get a value of -1 for the first constant in my enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have an enum declared in my model 'Payment' that does not correspond to a column in the database.

```
enum payment_method: [ :cash, :debit_card, :credit_card, :paypal ]
```

I can get the integer values for an enum from the class the enum is on:

```
Payment.payment_methods
```

This returns

```
{ "cash" => 0, "debit_card" => 1 ... }
```

However, I want the values returned to start with -1 instead of 0 like so.

```
{ "cash" => -1, "debit_card" => 0 ... }
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious why it matters. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
enum payment_method: { cash: -1, debit_card: 0, credit_card: 1, paypal: 2 }
```